# Docker image works only on Ubuntu & Windows 10, but fails on Amazon Linux

Tags: r, docker

I have a Docker image based on `rocker/r-base 4.2.1` containing an R Shiny App.
The image is build on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 where it runs successfully. Then, I save it to tar.gz with `docker save the_image | gzip > the_image.tar.gz` [as described in the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/).
Then, this [image is loaded](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) into Windows 10 and Linux Amazon 2 with `docker load --input the_image.tar.gz`. Mysteriously, the image runs fine on Windows 10, but fails on Amazon Linux as:

```
> docker run the_image
time="2022-10-14T17:35:45.942475641+02:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/4adab3705307279e9a188a3b12f54397dac1cdde254d070901700222b02581f1 pid=3255
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 2: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max

R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
> shiny::runApp('/root/app')
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
  error: cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'uname' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
Execution halted
INFO[2022-10-14T17:35:46.892198957+02:00] ignoring event                                container=4adab3705307279e9a188a3b12f54397dac1cdde254d070901700222b02581f1 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
INFO[2022-10-14T17:35:46.893071726+02:00] shim disconnected                             id=4adab3705307279e9a188a3b12f54397dac1cdde254d070901700222b02581f1
ERRO[2022-10-14T17:35:46.893157706+02:00] copy shim log                                 error="read /proc/self/fd/14: file already closed"
```

Does someone have an idea what's wrong here? Thank you! :)

Comment: The message 'Cannot allocate memory' suggests a resource issue. You may need to allocate more memory on your Amazon linux.

Comment: No, definitely not a resource shortage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, figured it out: for some reason, elevating the command with `sudo` fails, but there is the [flag `--privileged`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) which make the Docker image run properly:

```
docker run --privileged=true the_image
```

### Edit

Be **careful!**
Keep in mind, that the `--privileged` flag [gives extended privileges to this container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) what may be a potentially open door for invaders.

Comment: I also encountered this problem, but when deploying a dockerised r shiny app to a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server. Using the flag `--privileged` allows the the container to access the /usr/bin folder located one directory level up from the root directory (access using `cd ..`), and therefore the `which` command which is needed to load utils and stats. Thanks bathyscapher!